# Unexplainable invalid HTTP_HOST errors in django/nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm regularly seeing very odd INVALID_HOST errors in django. The website domain (which will be known as example.com from here on out) is the only thing that nginx passes on to django. example.com is in the `django.conf.settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS`. Everything else goes straight to nginx's 404. Here's the relevant lines in my config:

```
server { return 404; }
upstream django {
  server 127.0.0.1:3033;
}

server {
  listen      80;
  server_name classes.example.com;
  return 302 https://example.com/classes/;
}

server {
  listen      80;
  server_name *.example.com example.com;
  return 302 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
  if ($host ~* "^classes.example.com$") {
    rewrite ^.*(?=\/)(.+)$ https://example.com/classes/ permanent;
    break;
  }

  listen   443;
  root /home/django/example.com;
  server_name *.example.com example.com;

  # here are static files/ irrelevant code

  location / {
    uwsgi_pass django;
    include uwsgi_params;
  }
}
```

To me this says that I should never see the following message emailed to me.

`SuspiciousOperation: Invalid HTTP_HOST header (you may need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS): someotherdomainname.tld`

However I receive 4 or five of these a day via the standard django error logger. The `someotherdomain.tld` can be *.example.com (the wild card of my server), the server's ip address, or random things like device-metrics-us-2.amazon.com:443 or data.flurry.com to name a few. To make matters even more confusing, I can go to the server IP address or whatever.example.com and I get the nginx 404 screen with no error email (the expected behavior).

I am fairly certain that this is caused by the fact that if you log into our public wifi at the company the site is for you have to sign in as a guest and then it redirects you to our website (annoying but the CEO insists...). The errors are harmless and no one has ever reported seeing the django error page when they try to go to amazon.com or anything like that. I'm just stumped as to how it is even possible considering my nginx config.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have configured django correctly (`ALLOWED_HOSTS`); then it could be someone is simply spoofing headers.  Host spoofing is a common tactic to check for vulnerabilities.

You can prevent these entirely by denying anything other than what your server is responsible for:

```
if ($host !~* ^(example.com|classes.example.com|www.example.com)$) {
        return 444;
}
```